# Equivalent of Expression.Assign in .Net 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, expression-trees

In .Net 4.0 Microsoft added Expression.Assign.  I'm stuck with using 3.5, though.  I'm trying to come up with some means of write a method that can set the object property, but so far I haven't had much luck.  I can do this:

```
public void Assign(object instance, PropertyInfo pi, object value)
{
    pi.SetValue(instance, value, null);
}
```

But I want to avoid the overhead of using reflection!  Properties cannot be used with a `ref`.  Is this possible?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're aiming to avoid the overhead of reflection but are dealing with expression trees, I'm assuming you're trying to compile an expression to a delegate to set a property.

All properties are simply get and set methods behind the scenes.  These can be called - and this can be done in .NET 3.5 expression trees using `Expression.Call`.  For instance:

```
class Test{ public int X {get;set;} }

//...elsewhere
var xPropSetter = typeof(Test)
    .GetProperty("X",BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.Public)
    .GetSetMethod();
var newValPar=Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
var objectPar=Expression.Parameter(typeof(Test));
var callExpr=Expression.Call(objectPar, xPropSetter, newValPar);
var setterAction = (Action<Test,int>)
    Expression.Lambda(callExpr, objectPar, newValPar).Compile();
Test val = new Test();
Console.WriteLine(val.X);//0
setterLambda(val,42);
Console.WriteLine(val.X);//42
```

Note that if all you want is a delegate to set a value, you can also create the delegate without using an expression tree at all:

```
var setterAction = (Action<Test,int>)
    Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<Test,int>), xPropSetter);
```

Comment: Do you know any way to replace `Expression.Assign` is a situation when you need to assign value to your `Lambda`'s `ref` or `out` parameter? I couldn't find a way to do this.

Comment: I suspect that's not possible.  However, as a workaround, you could make helper methods such as `static void SetRef<T>(ref T reference, T val) {reference=val;}` and simply call that.  It's probably a *little* slower, but you might even get lucky and find the jit inlines it - it's a perfect candidate for inlining, anyhow...